# How to implement authentication with Azure Directory when using React Frontend and Django REST API backend?

Tags: reactjs, django, azure, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm just now learning Django REST Framework. However, I've been put on a project in charge of the DRF API. The project has a React frontend connected to a DRF API backend. I've made basic JWT Auth on the DRF API side before. However, we've been tasked with using Azure Directory for authentication. My question is how would this be setup? Would the Azure Directory auth be implemented on the frontend? What should be passed back and forth from the DRF API?

I'm just a little confused reading the documentation and what needs to be stored for login and sessions on the API vs the frontend. Any information would be helpful, whether it would be specifics or the general apparatus.

Answer (score 0):

To do this, you have to make use of the Microsoft Graph API.

Please refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/python

This will lead you to exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is an example of a full-stack django project. The current setup I'm working with is a React frontend and Django REST API backend stored separately on azure under the same directory. My confusion is what is handled with React and what is handled with Django API. I'll look through the link you provided and see if it provides some clarity.

Comment: @Kllicks You are not gonna get a full depth answer from anyone in stack overflow unless the question is so specific.